# How do I change same view in Windows 10(columns in explorer) to all type of folders to look same

Tags: windows

What I want to happen is that when I open File Explorer again the view stays same, regardless if is music or photos or documents folder.

Comment: You can try applying the view to all folders, but it does not stick and is not permanent. If you need a permanent explorer view, you need a third party app. I use xPlorer2 (zabkat) and it has had the same view for a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

This way:

- Open Windows Explorer and set the current folder to the desired view
- Click on the "View" tab
- Click on Options
- In the Folder Options dialog, go to the View tab
- Click on the "Apply to All Folders" button
- If prompted by a confirmation message, click "Yes"
- Click OK to complete.

This resets the view of all folders, but you can still change the view
of specific folders to be other than the new default.